# Adjust width of td with rotated headers

Tags: html, css

I have a table that uses javascript to show or hide some columns. All the column headers are rotated 90 degrees.

Everything works functionally, but there is one issue I haven't been able to figure out.
The width of the columns should be 20px. It appears that the width of the column is actually equal to the with of the div before it was actually rotated.

I have tried adjusting the width of the div inside the tds to be 20px. In this case the width of the column correctly adjusts to 20px, however the header text now appears cut off. I've tried compensating for this via setting overflow: visible; when the columns are visible, but then this appears to change the actual position of the Header divs. Any idea how I can get this working?

here is the code (background colors added only to help visualize position of div relative to td).

```js
function ShowHideMatrix() {
    var PrivCells = document.getElementsByClassName('PrivCol');
    var PrivMatrixCells = document.getElementsByClassName('PrivMatrixCol');

    for (var i = 0, iLen = PrivCells.length; i < iLen; i++) {
        if (PrivCells[i].style.height === '' || PrivCells[i].style.height != '0px') {
            PrivCells[i].style.height = '0px';
            PrivCells[i].style.width = '0px';
        } else {
            if(PrivCells[i].className.indexOf('PrivHead') > -1){
                PrivCells[i].style.height = '20px';
                PrivCells[i].style.width = '150px';
            } else {
                PrivCells[i].style.height = '20px';
                PrivCells[i].style.width = '20px';
            }
        }
    }
    
    for (var j = 0, iLen1 = PrivMatrixCells.length; j < iLen1; j++) {
        if (PrivMatrixCells[j].style.height === '' || PrivMatrixCells[j].style.height == '0px') {
            if(PrivMatrixCells[j].className.indexOf('PrivHead') > -1){
                PrivMatrixCells[j].style.height = '20px';
                PrivMatrixCells[j].style.width = '150px';
            } else {
                PrivMatrixCells[j].style.height = '20px';
                PrivMatrixCells[j].style.width = '20px';                
            }
        } else {
            PrivMatrixCells[j].style.height = '0px';
            PrivMatrixCells[j].style.width = '0px';
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.PrivHead {
    /* Rotation */
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE9+ */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari 3.1+, Chrome */
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg); /* FF3.5+ */
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Opera 10.5 */
    transform: rotate(90.0deg); /* Standard */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083); /* IE6,IE7 */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083)"; /* IE8 */
    //transform-origin: center center;
    /* Text */
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    //height: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: left;
    //position: relative;
}

.PrivCol {
    /* Transition */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.8s;
    -o-transition: all 0.8s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.8s;
    transition: all 0.8s;
    vertical-align: bottom;    
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.PrivMatrixCol {
    /* Transition */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.8s;
    -o-transition: all 0.8s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.8s;
    transition: all 0.8s;
    
    width: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
}

.PrivText{
    width: 100%;
}
table{
    width: 400px;
}
table, tr, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 0;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table id="Table0" style="margin-top: 100px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"> 
                    <button onclick="ShowHideMatrix()" href="">Matrix</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="Body0">
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color: lightblue; height: 150px;">
                <div class="PrivHead PrivCol" style="background-color: lightgreen; width: 150px; position: relative;">Request</div>
            </td>
            <td style="background-color: lightblue; height: 150px;">
                <div class="PrivHead PrivCol" style="background-color: lightgreen; position: relative;">Recommend</div>
            </td>
            <td style="background-color: lightblue; height: 150px; width: 0px;">
                <div class="PrivHead PrivMatrixCol" style="background-color: lightgreen;">Demo</div>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="PrivCol" style="text-align: center;">
                    <input type="Checkbox" checked="checked" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="PrivCol" style="text-align: center;">
                    <input type="Checkbox" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="PrivMatrixCol" style="text-align: center;">&#8226;</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="PrivText">Priv 2</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/namyzarc/qnfe3bde/

Comment: Update:
After some playing around, I've gotten this to be presentable in all browsers (IE10+, Chrome, Opera, FF) EXCEPT Safari. I've updated the fiddle with the latest code...